# How do I check if ChildControlsCreated was changed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, user-controls

I am trying to check a control to make changes if ChildsControlsCreated is changed to true. How do I do that? I tried...

```
if (tempControl.ChildControlsCreated == false)
{
    //do something
}
```

with no luck. Any other ideas?

Comment: Try outputting the value of `ChildControlsCreated`. Also, use a `!` before `tempControl.ChildControlsCreated` instead of `== false`.

Comment: What exactly do you want to make?

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing your own control, or you are reusing a control from the framework, you could consider overriding the method [CreateChildControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.createchildcontrols.aspx)

In the instance where you are writing your own control, you would simply:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls() {

    // Add a LiteralControl to the current ControlCollection. 
    this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<p>New Child Control!</p>"));


    ChildControlsCreated = true;
}
```

In the instance where you are reusing a control from someone else, provided it's available for overriding, you could do something like:

```
public MyControl : SomeControl
{

    protected override void CreateChildControls() {

    base.CreateChildControls();


    ChildControlsCreated = true;
    } 

}
```

Note that in both cases, you now control when ChildControlsCreated is set. You could therefore extend this concept to adding an event to your control implementation, which would be fired when you set the value, letting any subscribers know that child controls have been created.